# SDK2: horizontal swim lanes with rallycardboard

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I'm thinking about creating a rally app using the rallycardboard in SDK2, but I'm wondering about the flexibility the rallycardboard xtype to do horizontal swim lanes.

What I'd like to do is make a story map app (as per Jeff Patton) that uses the mid-level portfolio items to define the lanes (backbone of the story map), and displays the lowest level of portfolio items as cards.  But I'd like to have horizontal swim lanes for upcoming releases-- so by moving a card up or down a row, it would change the release that it's assigned to.  That way you could easily map out a storymap that covers several releases.

I have not seen any other Rally SDK2 apps with this sort of a concept-- they all use vertical swim lanes, so I'm wondering if I'll have to dive into super deep sencha minutia to have both horizontal and vertical lanes-- does anybody have any suggestions for the best way to implement horizontal swim lanes using the rallycardboard in SDK2?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about agile development with [Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/about/what-is-rally) software.

Comment: The rally tag is described as: Technical questions about coding to Rally Software's various APIs including the App SDK, Ruby & .NET APIs, and Web Service API....and that's what this question is about...coding to the rally SDK

Comment: Currently AppSDK2 does not have horizontal swim lanes implemented. There is a Rally Idea that you may vote for: https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D1851

Comment: Thanks-- and I did vote that up, but that question is in the Kanban category-- this is a general question about what approach one would take using the SDK

Comment: Since this is not built-in in SDK, one potential approach is, for example, to have separate boards on the same page (the boards will be aligned vertically) that imitate horizontal swim lanes and move the cards not only across vertical swim lanes within respective boards, but also across boards, from one board to another, which will effectively be similar to moving cards across horizontal swim lanes.

Comment: This question is clearly about programming (that is, creating a storymap app with the Rally SDK), not about agile development as paulsm4 thought.